# 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm receiving this error message and my video tag is reloading every time I try to click on it or use the scrubber bar. Why? I heard that you get this message if you alter a variable in the directive that the directive itself is watching. This makes sense, but even if I comment out the line with `scope.state.tutorialNumber++` it makes no difference. What am I missing?

HTML

```
<video ng-click="clickPause()" poster="./poster.png" video-watcher class="video-js vjs-default-skin" id="myvideo" congrats="state.questionNumber" video-loader="[state.tutorialNumber, state.sectionNumber]" id="video" controls>
    <source type="video/mp4" src="{{sections[state.sectionNumber].tutorials[state.tutorialNumber].name}}.mp4"></source>
    <source type="video/webm" src="{{sections[state.sectionNumber].tutorials[state.tutorialNumber].name}}.webm"></source>
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

and the directive

```
app.directive('videoWatcher', function ($location) {
return function (scope, video, attrs) {
    scope.$watch(attrs.videoLoader, function () {
        $(video[0]).bind('ended', function () {
            $(this).unbind('ended');
            if (!this.ended) {
                return;
            };
            var url = "/"+sections[scope.state.sectionNumber].name +"/"+ scope.state.tutorialNumber++;
            $location.path(url);
            scope.$apply();
        });
        setPause(scope.sections[scope.state.sectionNumber].tutorials[scope.state.tutorialNumber].pause);
        video[0].load();
        video[0].play();
    });
    scope.$watch(attrs.congrats, function(){
        if (scope.state.questionNumber === scope.sections[scope.state.sectionNumber].tutorials[scope.state.tutorialNumber].material.length){
            video[0].play();
            setTimeout(function () {
                video[0].play();
            }, 500);
        }
    });
};
})
```

EDIT: Ok, If I comment out the first `$watch` I don't get the error but if I comment all the code out inside of the first watch I do get the error. It seems to simply be the fact that I'm watching an array `[state.tutorialNumber, state.sectionNumber]`. I thought that was fine. Could it be the fact I'm using angular 1.0.4?

Comment: Can you post a pulnkr of the issue please?

Comment: A digest loop happens when a value is updated and never settles. Do you have multiple bits of code that edit the `videoLoader` attribute?

Comment: I edited the post for more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding the third parameter to `$watch` the `objectEquality` boolean.

```
$watch(attrs.videoLoader, function(){...}, true)
```